# highcharts csv export plugin

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

Highcharts provides an example for exporting chart series data to csv. (http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2495153-export-chart-data-to-csv-excel-and-more-via-dat)

Hitting the 'Alert CSV' button several time, you'll begin to see that the series name is duplicated with each click resulting in a badly structured csv output.

I've tried using unshift to add the series name to the series.yData array directly instead of the columns array but I receive the same output.

I also tried adding the series.name only if it wasn't part of the columns array but that did not work either.  Unshift is adding the series.name to the columns array for each click.

I read that unshift had some problems in I.E. 8 and earlier but I was not able to find any other known issues with it.

Why is unshift adding the series name each time the csv download is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, they push the xAxis.categories into the empty array columns. They then use unshift on the first element of columns, which is also xAxis.categories. unshift modifies the array it is used on, unlike other functions that return a modified array. The element in columns is a reference to the same object as xAxis.categories so it is modifying that array. This will be apparent if you resize the panes on the jsFiddle, triggering a chart redraw. All of this applies to the series.yData as well.

What they need to do is make a deep copy of the xAxis.categories array and the series.yData instead of just pushing it into the columns array.

```
if (xAxis.categories) {
  var tmpArr = [];
  $.each(xAxis.categories, function(index, value) {
    tmpArr.push(value); 
  });
  columns.push(tmpArr);
  columns[0].unshift("");
}
each (this.series, function (series) {
  var tmpArr = [];
  $.each(series.yData, function(index, value) {
    tmpArr.push(value); 
  });
  columns.push(tmpArr);
  columns[columns.length - 1].unshift(series.name);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cqjvD/102/

Although using jQuery merge would probably be an easier way of doing this too.

```
if (xAxis.categories) {
  columns.push($.merge([""], xAxis.categories);
}
each (this.series, function (series) {
  columns.push($.merge([series.name], series.yData));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  However, I am still unsure why the original example shows the series name being appended to itself after each click.

Comment: When they do "columns.push(xAxis.categories)" it is not creating a new copy of that array. The first element in columns references the same variable as xAxis.categories. So when they unshift, to modify columns[0], they also modify xAxis.categories because both reference the same value in memory. So when xAxis.categories is used on each subsequent click, it has already been modified by the previous iteration and they build up each time. The same applies to series.yData. Not sure how else to put it. Do you understand the difference between reference and value variables?

Comment: Got it Scott!  Thank you for taking the time to explain.  For me, I didn't realize that objects and arrays are pushed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also shift values after exporting: http://jsfiddle.net/cqjvD/104/

```
    each (this.series, function (series) {
        series.yData.shift();
    });
    xAxis.categories.shift();
```